# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined at HTMLFormElement.onmouseover

Tags: javascript, forms, smf-forum

I am using this snippet:

```
onmouseover="this.title=this.options[this.selectedIndex].title"
```

so that I can add **title** tags in dropdown menu text.

```
<form name="searchform" onmouseover="this.title=this.options[this.selectedIndex].title" onsubmit="return doSearch();" accept-charset="', $context['character_set'], '">
<input class="search_input" type="text" name="search" value="" />
<input class="search_button" type="submit" name="submit" value="" />
<select class="search_select" name="sengines" onchange="return saveOption();">
<option value="?action=search2;search=" title="Full forum search">Forum</option>
```

The error I get when I check with browser tools is

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined at HTMLFormElement.onmouseover
```

Comment: make sure sth is selected first! better to use `addEventListener` instead of `onmouseover` and use an event handler where you can test if sth is indeed selected rather than hardcoding the handler in html `onmouseover` attribute

Comment: Thanks, not sure how to implement that on the code...

Comment: first try adding `onmouseover` NOT on the form element but one the `select ` element. Then read about [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) and use it

Comment: Funnilly, the title tag still displayed without the JavaScript snippet. So solution was simpler...

Answer (score 0):

you need bind the function of the event listener in this case

```
<form name="searchform" onmouseover="function(this)" onsubmit="return doSearch();" accept-charset="', $context['character_set'], '">
```

the this means the current tag/element will passed by parameter of the event

```
 onmouseover="function(this)"
```

well you add the event in the element that you want, or acces to child like you do

```
this.options[this.selectedIndex].title
```